# reading packed hexadecimal data from mainframe and converting it into decimal format

Tags: java, hex

I am doing a project on converting the *packed hexadecimal data* of mainframes to decimal / human readable format using Java. But the data in the file is like:

```
00011111112       201343    /…æ     
          &c                                               ï%                                                               “*   œ“fæ     —æ          r<   Ìð    
Œ    êŒ000000 000000          q@00000000                  ð                                                   
00011111112       201345    àr<         
          ™                                                                                                                 r<   Ìð     †          Ë…ð   Ë<    Êð    àã000000 000000          q00000000      @            %                                                   
00011111112       201346     Œ                ì                                                                                                                Ë…ð   Ë<         %          é-   ÅÇ    …e*    Äæ000000 000000          ræ00000000   @   Œ
```

I don't know how to convert that to the decimal format using Java. I am using `wing for the UI part.

Can anyone help and provide me with any algorithm or working code?

This is the screenshot of a sample set of data where the first line represents the packed hexadecimal data. next 2 lines represents the converted data.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to know what the format is, and work using bytes. Use `InputStream` and not `Reader`, remember that mainframes may use EBCDIC instead of ASCII, and mey $DEITY help your soul.

In all seriousness, you will need to know the wire format of what you want to do. Find that first, it's documented somewhere. (Hopefully; it's a mainframe, so who knows).

Comment: Sorry but that did not work. i am already using InputStream in my program.

Comment: I have a snapshot of the actual data and the converted data. but im nt able to post. with that i can give u a clear idea of how the data actually looks after the conversion of the packed hex.

Comment: As I wrote in the answer, you will need to know the format of the packed data if you want to convert it to human readable. You could start with a [hex dump](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_dump) of your data, and going from there.

Comment: can u help me to convert from comp-3 format to hexadecimal..?

Comment: No, but few things are there in that which is explained in that page.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you mean packed binary coded decimals, BCD.

As you know a byte is 8 bits, representable in base 16, hexadecimal as two hex digits 0-9,A-F.
BCD now codeds a number string as 1234, a string with hex bytes 31, 32, 33, 34 packed as 12, 34.

```
boolean fromBCD(byte ch) {
   (ch & 0xF) < 10 && ((ch >> 4) & 0xF) < 10;
}

int fromBCD(byte ch) {
   (ch & 0xF) + 10 * ((ch >> 4) & 0xF)
}
```